# Viewing tag feeds is broken

Tags: support, bug, tags

I'm clicking on some of my Watched Tags on StackOverflow and getting an  intermittent error for some (not all) of them:

> No questions found. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

When viewing the "Newest" tab.

For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idhttp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp

---

**UPDATE**: I just refreshed the main Meta page and got this error and no feed content:

> It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.

Comment: that meta error is somewhat common

Comment: It's working for me. The site has been randomly giving me 500 errors the past few minutes, so it could just be a temporary issue.

Comment: I don't visit Meta often, but I've never seen that error before, on either site.  But I frequent StackOverflow many times a day and I've never seen it behave the way I described.

Comment: I was also [having problems searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394493/323179) a few minutes ago, but I think it's working now.

Comment: Possibly related bug reported on MSE: [Search seems to be almost completely broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394493)

Comment: Yes, it is working again, so the rollback must have fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is the same issue I was having, [Josh Zhang reported it was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394495/323179):

> Thank you for the report, we deployed some changes at 19:13 UTC. We started to see service degradation in our monitoring software and began investigating internally. At 19:38 UTC we opted to roll back the breaking change which restored search functionality.